# How do I come up with a loop invariant for a pseudocode that calculates an odd number?

Tags: loops, numbers, pseudocode, loop-invariant

I'm struggling to come up with a loop invariant for the following piece of code:

OddNumber(n)

1. a = 2
2. for i = 1 to n do
3. ```
      a = a * i
   ```
4. return a+1

Now, I want to find a loop invariant which is correct before entering the for-loop in l.2.
My idea was that a = the product from k=1 to i-1 multiplied with 2, however, I have trouble involving the 1 added in the end.

Comment: `a` is always even - this is the loop invariant.

Comment: then how would I go on to prove this via induction?

Comment: Easy. Base is a=2 - it is even. Then an even number multiplied by any other (natural) number is always even too.

Comment: But the value of 1 gets added at the end of the loop, so a can never be even, can it? No matter how often you multiply the value of a by i, in the end you always have to add 1

Comment: So? The invariant is still there, `a` is even. Any even number + 1 is odd. What are you trying to prove?

Comment: Oh okay, I thought the fact that +1 was added needed to be part of the invariant. Since it's not, that makes much more sense now, thank you